# How can I handle a POJO like a bean?

Tags: java, reflection, javabeans

How can I access a simple java object as a bean?

For example:

```
class Simple {
    private String foo;
    String getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }
    private void setFoo( String foo ) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}
```

Now I want to use this object like this:

```
Simple simple = new Simple();
simple.setFoo( "hello" );

checkSettings( simple );
```

So I'm looking for the implementation of the method `checkSettings( Object obj )`:

```
public boolean checkSettings( Object obj ) {
    // pseudocode here
    Bean bean = new Bean( obj );
    if( "hello".equals( bean.getAttribute( "foo" ) ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The java language contains a package called `java.beans` which sounds like it could help me. But I don't find a good starting point.

Any hints?

Comment: Sorry but this question does not make sense to me. A bean is simply a class with a public no-args ctor and get/set methods.

Comment: I don't want to call the getter explicitly. I want to use a bean like interface like shown in the method `checkSettings()`.

Comment: I'm still confused. The Bean interface shown is nothing to do be Java Beans as far as I can tell.

Comment: There is no class named "Bean" in the standard JDK - so it would be helpful if you provided what package that class came from.

Comment: I intended to put some pseudo code here, like the comment says. But I must admit, it doesn't look like (but please read it as if).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html) yields an object implementing [`java.beans.BeanInfo`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/beans/BeanInfo.html), which in turn can be used to get `PropertyDescriptor`s and `MethodDescriptor`s (via its `getPropertyDescriptors`- and `getMethodDescriptors`-methods), which in turn can be used to get the information you actually want.

It is not really less effort than using reflection.

Comment: OK, now I have a PropertyDescriptor. How can I use it to read an attribute from a given object?

Comment: Got it. `value = PropertyDescriptor.getReadMethod.invoke( object )`. A bit complicated, but I'm more flexible this way than with apache beanutils. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I think the functionality you're looking for resembles the one from the BeanUtils class of apache-commons:

http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/

Take a look at the getProperty() method of BeanUtils.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the question comments above I'm still not sure what you want, but it sort of sounds like you want to wrap an object gets & sets to an interface with a getAttribute. This is not what I think of as a "bean".

So you have an interface:

```
interface Thingie {
     Object getAttribute(String attribute);
}
```

You would have to write an implementation of that that uses reflection.

```
class Thingie {
  Object wrapped;

  public Object getAttribute(String attribute) throws Exception {
      Method[] methods = wrapped.getClass().getMethods();
      for(Method m : methods) {
        if (m.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("get"+attribute)) {
           return m.invoke(wrapped);
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Except that `isFoo` is a valid name for a boolean property named `foo` and `GetFoo` is *not* a valid name for a getter and `getFoo(int index)` is not a Bean getter and, and, and, ... Basically the Bean specification is pretty specific and this code implements only a very small subset of it.